# ASA A/S with CSC Module requirements?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Last weekend we tryed to cluster two ASA5510 in an active / Standby szenario. Unfortunatelly it failed, because one ASA has an CSC ASA-SSM-CSC-10-K9= (+ Secplus and 250user license) module installed, the other ASA doesn't have.

We tryed it with 8.2(5) and also with 8.4 release, both trys failed "hardware blabla CSC"

So the question now is, if we buy another ASA-SSM-CSC-10-K9= Module for the standby appliance, does this module also need an equivalent amount of licenses  -> Secplus and 250user license
or is only the hardware required and the license move during a failover.

We prefer pre 8.3 release, because of the crappy NAT syntax, but i guess that the license merging/moving is only possible with 8.3+ releases,  can someone confirm that?

Comment: The new NAT syntax isn't crappy - just different.  You should learn it, and not hold yourself back from new versions of the ASA OS just because you don't want to learn the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should ask your Cisco vendor this - then you have someone properly accountable should it not turn out the way you hope.